# Rails Zeitwerk not respecting class in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

Running rails `zeitwerk:check` returns `expected file app/api/mariana_tek_client.rb to define constant MarianaTekClient`

The odd thing is that I have the following class defined in this file, which seems to follow the convention that I've seen documented: `project/app/api/mariana_tek_client.rb`

```
module Api
  class MarianaTekClient
    include HTTParty
  end
end
```

If I remove the module from the file and leave the class definition only, Zeitwerk stops failing, but this is contrary to what I've seen in all its docs. Plus, I want my namespace!

This works:

```
class MarianaTekClient
  include HTTParty
end
```

Would love if someone can clue me into why its failing with the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you've added `app/api` as an extra autoload path.  If so, Zeitwerk will look in that folder for classes in the root namespace, and subfolders for classes in modules - so it expects `app/api/mariana_tek_client.rb` to contain `MarianaTekClient`; if you want `Api::MarianaTekClient` then that would need to go in `app/api/api/mariana_tek_client.rb`.

You *could* point Zeitwerk at `app`, and it would then look for `Api::MarianaTekClient` in `app/api/mariana_tek_client.rb`; but [that is discouraged](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38725) and would probably cause you more problems in the long term.

I'd recommend using the default Zeitwerk configuration, and putting your model classes under `app/models`; so it would then look for `Api::MarianaTekClient` in `app/models/api/mariana_tek_client.rb` - as would anyone else working on your code.

Comment: Really appreciate the swift response! Don't know why I did not consider that. This is not a DB model, so I don't want to put it in models. I'll likely go with the nested `api/api` folder or remove the module in the worst case.